# boostrap card image on body of layout page overlaps on top of footer's playlist list

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-4

I have a mvc layout page,_Layout.cshtml as follow. I have mediaelementjs playlist on footer section(_footer.cshtml), and in the RenderBody of layout(which renders Index.cshtml) it has bootstrap card which has a vinyl music player, both of which playlist and cards, are created dynamically. The card's image overlaps on top of the playlist. the same case happens with the dropdown notification list on top menu with side navbar. The side navbar overlaps on top of the top notification dropdown as shown in the image below. How do I correct this?

[Overlaps of controls in RenderBody on top of sections in _Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNjY6.jpg)

Code of Layout

```
        <body>
            <div class="page home-page">
                <!-- Main Navbar-->
                @*<header class="header">
                    </header>*@
                <div class="page-content d-flex align-items-stretch">
                    <!-- Side Navbar -->
                    <nav id="sidebar" class="side-navbar">
                        <!-- Sidebar Header -->

                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li>
                                <a id="menu-toggle" class="btn">
                                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>MusicCloud
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li> <a href="index.html"><i class="icon-home"></i>Home</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#dashvariants" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="collapse"> <i class="icon-interface-windows"></i>Dropdown </a>

                            </li>
                            <li> <a href="tables.html"> <i class="icon-grid"></i>Tables </a></li>
                            <li> <a href="charts.html"> <i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i>Charts </a></li>
                            <li> <a href="forms.html"> <i class="icon-padnote"></i>Forms </a></li>
                            <li> <a href="login.html"> <i class="icon-interface-windows"></i>Login Page</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </nav>
                    <div class="content-inner">
                        <!-- Page Header-->
                        <header class="page-header">
                            <nav class="navbar">
                                <!-- Search Box-->
                                <div class="search-box">
                                    <button class="dismiss"><i class="icon-close"></i></button>
                                    <form id="searchForm" action="#" role="search">
                                        <input type="search" placeholder="What are you looking for..." class="form-control">
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div class="container-fluid">
                                    <div class="navbar-holder d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                                        <!-- Navbar Menu -->
                                        <ul class="nav-menu list-unstyled d-flex flex-md-row align-items-md-center">
                                            <!-- Search-->
                                            <li class="nav-item d-flex align-items-center"><a id="search" href="#"><i class="icon-search"></i></a></li>
                                            <!-- Notifications-->
                                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                                <a id="notifications" rel="nofollow" data-target="#" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i><span class="badge bg-red">12</span></a>
                                                <ul aria-labelledby="notifications" class="dropdown-menu">
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a rel="nofollow" href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                                                            <div class="notification">
                                                                <div class="notification-content"><i class="fa fa-envelope bg-green"></i>You have 6 new messages </div>
                                                                <div class="notification-time"><small>4 minutes ago</small></div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a rel="nofollow" href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                                                            <div class="notification">
                                                                <div class="notification-content"><i class="fa fa-twitter bg-blue"></i>You have 2 followers</div>
                                                                <div class="notification-time"><small>4 minutes ago</small></div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a rel="nofollow" href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                                                            <div class="notification">
                                                                <div class="notification-content"><i class="fa fa-upload bg-orange"></i>Server Rebooted</div>
                                                                <div class="notification-time"><small>4 minutes ago</small></div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a rel="nofollow" href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                                                            <div class="notification">
                                                                <div class="notification-content"><i class="fa fa-twitter bg-blue"></i>You have 2 followers</div>
                                                                <div class="notification-time"><small>10 minutes ago</small></div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li><a rel="nofollow" href="#" class="dropdown-item all-notifications text-center"> <strong>view all notifications                                            </strong></a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                            <!-- Messages                        -->
                                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                                <a id="messages" rel="nofollow" data-target="#" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i><span class="badge bg-orange">10</span></a>
                                                <ul aria-labelledby="notifications" class="dropdown-menu">
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a rel="nofollow" href="#" class="dropdown-item d-flex">
                                                            <div class="msg-profile"> <img src="~/Content/Template/img/avatar-1.jpg" alt="..." class="img-fluid rounded-circle"></div>
                                                            <div class="msg-body">
                                                                <h3 class="h5">Jason Doe</h3><span>Sent You Message</span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a rel="nofollow" href="#" class="dropdown-item d-flex">
                                                            <div class="msg-profile"> <img src="~/Content/Template/img/avatar-2.jpg" alt="..." class="img-fluid rounded-circle"></div>
                                                            <div class="msg-body">
                                                                <h3 class="h5">Frank Williams</h3><span>Sent You Message</span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a rel="nofollow" href="#" class="dropdown-item d-flex">
                                                            <div class="msg-profile"> <img src="~/Content/Template/img/avatar-3.jpg" alt="..." class="img-fluid rounded-circle"></div>
                                                            <div class="msg-body">
                                                                <h3 class="h5">Ashley Wood</h3><span>Sent You Message</span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li><a rel="nofollow" href="#" class="dropdown-item all-notifications text-center"> <strong>Read all messages    </strong></a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                            <!-- Logout    -->
                                            <li class="nav-item"><a href="login.html" class="nav-link logout">Logout<i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </nav>
                            <div class="container-fluid">
                                <!-- Ticker-->
                                @Html.Partial("_TopNav")
                            </div>
                        </header>
                        <!-- Dashboard Counts Section-->
                        <section class="dashboard-counts no-padding-bottom">
                            <div class="container-fluid">
                                <div class="row bg-white has-shadow">
                                    <!-- Item -->
                                    @RenderBody()
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </section>

                        <!-- Dashboard Header Section    -->
                        <!-- Feeds Section-->
                        <!-- Updates Section                                                -->
                        <!-- Page Footer-->
                        <footer class="sticky-footer">
                            @*<div class="container-fluid">
                                <div class="row">*@
                            @Html.Partial("_fullPlayer")
                            @*</div>
                                </div>*@
                        </footer>

                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="modPlayList" class="modcon" style="width: 20%;height:20%"></div>
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
            @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/mediaelement")
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modules")
            @RenderSection("scripts", false)
        </body>
```

Comment: You need to post the *output* HTML and specify the version of Bootstrap you are using.

Comment: @WebDevBooster                               
                               https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48932191/bootstrap-responsive-layout-asp-net-mvc-dont-work