# Bootstrap Responsive Layout Asp.Net MVC don't work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-4

I am new to bootstrap with asp.net Mvc. How to create a responsive layout as the below image? My layout moves when I collapse the side menu. And the page is not responsive at all? Do I need to give mediaqueries for all partial views that I render in the _layout.cshtml?

[Home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koUPq.jpg)

[LayoutAlteredWhenMenuCollapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4rSe.jpg)

**Page View Source**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
        <title>Index</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="robots" content="all,follow">
        <!-- Tweaks for older IEs-->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <!-- Javascript files-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
                integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-----playlist------>
        <style>
            .sticky-footer {
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 100%;
            }

            /*original*/
            .liked::before {
                color: #600;
                content: '\f004';
            }

            .not-liked::before {
                color: #aaa;
                content: '\f08a';
            }
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#menu-toggle').on('click', function () {
                    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
                });

            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page home-page">
            <!-- Main Navbar-->
            <div class="page-content d-flex align-items-stretch">
                <!-- Side Navbar -->
                <nav id="sidebar" class="side-navbar">
                    <!-- Sidebar Header -->
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li>
                            <a id="menu-toggle" class="btn">
                                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>MusicCloud
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li> <a href="index.html"><i class="-home"></i>Home</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#daiconshvariants" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="collapse"> <i class="icon-interface-windows"></i>Dropdown </a>
                        </li>
                        <li> <a href="tables.html"> <i class="icon-grid"></i>Tables </a></li>
                        <li> <a href="charts.html"> <i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i>Charts </a></li>
                        <li> <a href="forms.html"> <i class="icon-padnote"></i>Forms </a></li>
                        <li> <a href="login.html"> <i class="icon-interface-windows"></i>Login Page</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="content-inner">
                    <!-- Page Header-->
                    <header class="page-header">
                        <nav class="navbar">
                            <!-- Ticker-->
                            <div>
                                <div class="headerTop">
                                    <div id="breakingnews">
                                        <span class="breakhead"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i></span>
                                        <div id="adbreakingnews">Loading...</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Search Box-->
                                <div class="search-box">
                                    <button class="dismiss"><i class="icon-close"></i></button>
                                    <form id="searchForm" action="#" role="search">
                                        <input type="search" placeholder="What are you looking for..." class="form-control">
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                                    <!-- Navbar Header-->
                                    <!-- Navbar Menu -->
                                    <ul class="nav-menu list-unstyled d-flex flex-md-row align-items-md-center">
                                        <!-- Search-->
                                        <li class="nav-item d-flex align-items-center"><a id="search" href="#"><i class="icon-search"></i></a></li>
                                        <!-- Notifications-->
                                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                            <a id="notifications" rel="nofollow" data-target="#" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i><span class="badge bg-red">12</span></a>
                                            <ul aria-labelledby="notifications" class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li>
                                                    <a rel="nofollow" href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                                                        <div class="notification">
                                                            <div class="notification-content"><i class="fa fa-envelope bg-green"></i>You have 6 new messages </div>
                                                            <div class="notification-time"><small>4 minutes ago</small></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a rel="nofollow" href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                                                        <div class="notification">
                                                            <div class="notification-content"><i class="fa fa-twitter bg-blue"></i>You have 2 followers</div>
                                                            <div class="notification-time"><small>4 minutes ago</small></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a rel="nofollow" href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                                                        <div class="notification">
                                                            <div class="notification-content"><i class="fa fa-upload bg-orange"></i>Server Rebooted</div>
                                                            <div class="notification-time"><small>4 minutes ago</small></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a rel="nofollow" href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                                                        <div class="notification">
                                                            <div class="notification-content"><i class="fa fa-twitter bg-blue"></i>You have 2 followers</div>
                                                            <div class="notification-time"><small>10 minutes ago</small></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li><a rel="nofollow" href="#" class="dropdown-item all-notifications text-center"> <strong>view all notifications                                            </strong></a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <!-- Messages                        -->
                                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                            <a id="messages" rel="nofollow" data-target="#" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i><span class="badge bg-orange">10</span></a>
                                            <ul aria-labelledby="notifications" class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li>
                                                    <a rel="nofollow" href="#" class="dropdown-item d-flex">
                                                        <div class="msg-profile"> <img src="/Content/Template/img/avatar-1.jpg" alt="..." class="img-fluid rounded-circle"></div>
                                                        <div class="msg-body">
                                                            <h3 class="h5">Jason Doe</h3><span>Sent You Message</span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a rel="nofollow" href="#" class="dropdown-item d-flex">
                                                        <div class="msg-profile"> <img src="/Content/Template/img/avatar-2.jpg" alt="..." class="img-fluid rounded-circle"></div>
                                                        <div class="msg-body">
                                                            <h3 class="h5">Frank Williams</h3><span>Sent You Message</span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a rel="nofollow" href="#" class="dropdown-item d-flex">
                                                        <div class="msg-profile"> <img src="/Content/Template/img/avatar-3.jpg" alt="..." class="img-fluid rounded-circle"></div>
                                                        <div class="msg-body">
                                                            <h3 class="h5">Ashley Wood</h3><span>Sent You Message</span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li><a rel="nofollow" href="#" class="dropdown-item all-notifications text-center"> <strong>Read all messages    </strong></a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <!-- Logout    -->
                                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="login.html" class="nav-link logout">Logout<i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </nav>
                    </header>
                    <!-- Dashboard Counts Section-->
                    <section class="dashboard-counts no-padding-bottom">
                        <div>
                            <div class="row bg-white has-shadow">
                                <!-- Item -->
                                <div id="container-fluid">
                                    <div class="row" id="contentPanel">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                    <!-- Page Footer-->
                    <footer id="sticky-footer" class="sticky-footer">
                        <style>
                            #mediawrapper {
                                margin-left: auto;
                                margin-right: auto;
                                margin-top: 30px;
                                width: 100%;
                            }

                            #mejsAudio {
                                width: 100%;
                            }

                            ​ h1 {
                                text-align: center;
                            }

                            .tagline {
                                text-align: center;
                            }


                            .sm2-bar-ui {
                                position: relative;
                                display: inline-block;
                                width: 100%;
                                font-family: helvetica, arial, verdana, sans-serif;
                                font-weight: 400;
                                -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
                                background-clip: padding-box;
                                /*-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;*/
                                -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
                                /*font-smoothing: antialiased;*/
                                text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
                                min-width: 20em;
                                max-width: 30em;
                                border-radius: 2px;
                                overflow: hidden;
                                transition: max-width .2s ease-in-out
                            }


                                .sm2-bar-ui.fixed {
                                    left: 0;
                                    top: auto;
                                    bottom: 0;
                                    overflow: visible
                                }

                                .sm2-bar-ui.full-width {
                                    max-width: 100%;
                                    z-index: 5
                                }

                            /*your desired height*/
                            footer1 {
                                width: 100%;
                                height: 20%;
                                position: absolute;
                                bottom: 0;
                                left: 0;
                            }

                            .mej-playlist-collapse-button {
                                cursor: pointer;
                                display: block;
                                font-size: 0;
                                line-height: 0;
                                text-decoration: none;
                                margin: 7px 5px;
                                padding: 0;
                                position: absolute;
                                height: 16px;
                                width: 16px;
                                border: 0;
                                float: left;
                            }
                        </style>
                        <div id="audioDiv">

                            <audio id="mejsAudio" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay"
                                   data-cast-title="Chromecast"
                                   data-cast-description="Cast your playlist"
                                   data-cast-poster="~/bower_components/mediaelement/build/chromecast.png">
                                Your browser does not support the audio element.
                                <button class="fa-archive"></button>
                            </audio>
                        </div>
                        <button class="mej-playlist-collapse-button"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></button>
                    </footer>
                </div>
                <div id="right" class="chatBarNav">
                    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20160511/json2.js"></script>
                    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
                    <link href="/Content/css/ChatStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
                    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
                    <script src="/Scripts/Modules/Home/ChatBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
                    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
                    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
                    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
                    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>
                    <style>
                        .input-group i.fa {
                            position: absolute;
                            top: 10px;
                            left: 22px;
                            color: #808080;
                            font-size: 22px;
                            z-index: 9999;
                        }

                        .fa-loggedInUser {
                            margin-left: 4px;
                            color: #009aff;
                        }

                        .fa-active {
                            color: #0cdb2a;
                            margin-left: 4px;
                            margin-right: 2px;
                        }

                        .form-control {
                            position: relative;
                            padding-left: 45px !important;
                        }
                    </style>

                    <div id="divContainer" class="aside-md bg-light dk">
                        <h4 class="font-thin m-l-md m-t fa fa-connectdevelop">You are Connected</h4>
                        <div id="divLogin" class="login">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                <input id="txtNickName" type="text" class="form-control custom-input is-invalid" name="name" value="" placeholder="Enter name" required autofocus style="border-radius: 30px;">
                            </div>
                            <div id="divButton">
                                <input id="btnStartChat" style="color:black;" type="button" class="submitButton" value="Start Chat" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="divChat" class="chatRoom">
                            <div class="title">
                                Welcome to MChat [<span id='spanUser'></span>]

                            </div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <div id="divChatWindow" class="chatWindow">
                                </div>
                                <div id="divusers" class="users">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div style="clear:both"></div>

                            <div class="input-group mb-3 messageBar">
                                <input type="text" id="txtMessage" class="form-control" placeholder="Type" aria-label="Text" aria-describedby="basic-addon">
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <button id="btnSendMsg" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input id="hdId" type="hidden" />
                        <input id="hdUserName" type="hidden" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="modPlayList" class="modcon" style="width: 20%;height:20%"></div>
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
        <script src="/Content/Template/vendor/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/Content/Template/vendor/popper.js/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/Content/Template/vendor/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
        <link href="/Content/Template/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="/Content/Template/css/fontastic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="/Content/Template/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="/Content/Poppins.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="/Content/Template/css/style.default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="/Content/Template/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="/Content/Template/img/favicon.ico" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="/Content/SideBar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="/Content/Album/css/albums.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="/Scripts/MediaElementJS/js/mediaelement-and-player_2.13.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="/Scripts/MediaElementJS/mep-feature-playlist-master/mep-feature-playlist.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="/Content/Album/css/ticker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="/Content/css/WeatherCard.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
        <script src="/Content/Template/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/MediaElementJS/js/mediaelement-and-player_2.13.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/MediaElementJS/mep-feature-playlist-master/mep-feature-playlist.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/Modules/Albums/FullPlayer.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/Modules/Albums/Ticker.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/Modules/Albums/Song_Layout.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/Modules/Home/Weather.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Since when do we load css files at the *end* of a document? Start by reducing this output HTML to a [mcve] and loading css files in the head of the document. No one is gonna dig through that huge thing. You need to reduce the code to the part that's not working and leave out everything else.

Comment: Remove the links to all of the css and js files that aren't necessary to demonstrate/reproduce the issue. Start removing them one by one and each time you remove one, verify that the issue is still there.

Comment: @WebDevBooster Ok I made a mistake with the css at the end of layout but how can I paste all the partial views and body code plus css and jquery that are rendered in Layout page, I can paste only 30K characters here. Each part is neccesary code. Please atleast give me an idea of how to implement such a responsive layout with basic right,left sidebars,footer and top menu(they are partial views)? Do i need to specify mediaqueries for each of this partial views or only the layout?

Comment: Open the page in a browser window, view source and copy the code from there. But again: Make sure you remove everything (one by one) that's not necessary to demonstrate/reproduce the issue. Read this: [mcve]